# JavaScript - Fade in and Fade out function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. My goal here is fade in and out the box. Please review my code and let me know what am doing wrong here? When a user clicks Fade, the box should change opacity? I tried to define function fade button and call the function and execute the toggle fade in and out, but it appears to be not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Watch That Box</title>
  </head>

  <style>
      .fade-in {
          opacity: 1;
      }   
  </style>
  
  <body>
      <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>
      
      <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px;"></div>
      
      <button onclick="growbutton()"> Grow </button>
      <button onclick="fadebutton()"> Fade </button>
      <button onclick="resetbutton()"> Reset </button>
      <button onclick="bluebutton()"> Blue </button>

      <script>
          const box = document.getElementById("box");
          function fadebutton() {
              box.classList.toggle("fade-in");
          }
       </script>
       <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `opacity` style defaults to `1` so adding and removing the class is unnoticeable. Therefore I updated the `opacity` style to `0.5`.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");
const fade = document.getElementById("fade");

/* Click event listener for <button> with id value of "fade" */
fade.addEventListener("click", function() {
  box.classList.toggle("fade-in");
});
```

```css
.fade-in {
  /* The style below has been updated. */
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#box {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:orange;
  margin:25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box"></div>

  <button id="fade">Fade</button>
</body>
```

---

The code snippet below demonstrates the implementation of the above solution within an HTML file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Watch That Box</title>
  </head>

  <style>
      .fade-in {
          opacity: 0.5; /* The style below has been updated. */
      }   
      
      #box {
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        background-color:orange;
        margin:25px;
      }
  </style>
  
  <body>
      <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>
      
      <div id="box"></div>
      
      <button id="fade">Fade</button>

      <script>
          const box = document.getElementById("box");
          const fade = document.getElementById("fade");

          /* Click event listener for <button> with id value of "fade" */
          fade.addEventListener("click", function() {
              box.classList.toggle("fade-in");
          });
       </script>
  </body>
</html>
```